# The best way to get read only data using EF and support sporting/searching/filtering

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Lets say that I need to execute this query with EF in business layer

```
var list = context.Invoices.Select(x => new
{
    InvoiceNumber = x.InvoiceNUmber,
    InvoiceDate = x.InvoiceDate,
    CustomerName = x.Customer.CustomerName,
    TotalValue = x.InvoiceData.Sum(y => y.Quantity * y.Price),
    Id = x.Id
}).ToList();
```

What can I do for this list to be easily sortable, searchable or filterable in UI layer?

Thanks,
Goran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is to return a object that is not anonymous.  That is, create a class to hold this data.  It should either have an implicit zero-argument constructor (because you have no constructors), or an explicit zero-argument one (because you have defined other constructors).  Then you can say:

```
List<MyObject> list = context.Invoices.Select(x => new MyObject()
{
    InvoiceNumber = x.InvoiceNUmber,
    InvoiceDate = x.InvoiceDate,
    CustomerName = x.Customer.CustomerName,
    TotalValue = x.InvoiceData.Sum(y => y.Quantity * y.Price),
    Id = x.Id
}).ToList();
```

Now you can return the strongly-typed list of objects out of your business layer, and your UI layer can use LINQ (or whatever) to do sorting/filtering/paging.

Comment: Note that you cannot return an anonymous type from a function unless you return an object and the use Reflection. (There are ways around this, such as tricks with casting or by using 'dynamic', but these are either hack-ish or error-prone.)

Comment: Hi anon, thanks for the response.
I know I am able to achieve this using strongly typed collections, but I was trying to have some lgeneric class that will allow me to use linq in UI, and provide different views of data. Do you think this approach is not good, and that we should update BLL anytime a customer wants different view in UI? Or maybe its the best thing to have this "View model classes" in UI?